# Javascript to Open Excel in Chrome

Tags: javascript, excel

Using Javascript, I am able to run a VBA function in IE. But doesn't work in Chrome. Any sample code in XMLHttPPbject etc.. to resolve this issue. I am fine with angular JS as well. need some sample logic

```
function test() {
        var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
        Excel.Visible = true;
        Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\TestFolder\\SumTest.xlsm");
        Excel.Run("Sheet1.msgbox1");
      }
```

Comment: ActiveX doesn't work in any other browser except Internet Explorer.

Comment: A modern browser will not be able to trigger a file to open from the user's disk. It's a security risk. The browser does not (and should not) have access to the local filesystem of the device, and certainly not without the user's explicit consent. That's one reason why ActiveX is no longer used (except in IE which effectively a legacy browser now).

Comment: Off the top of my head, here are some possible alternative approaches (which may or may not suit your scenario, with a bit of creative thinking): 1) Give the user written instructions about what to do (since the steps above are trivial). 2) Find some other way to deliver the content (e.g. host the document in Office365 and view in the browser, or don't use Excel for this functionality), 3) If this is an intranet app for a smaller group of users, you could investigate whether it's possible to develop a custom browser extension which could be given permissions to run similar code to this.

Comment: There might also be other ways to fulfil whatever your overall goal is here with this functionality. Like I said, time to get creative.